# Angularfire v2: is there a way to get a collection beginning with a specified index number?

Tags: firebase, angularfire

For instance:

```
  $scope.items = $firebase(new Firebase("https://****.firebaseio.com").startAt(100).limit(100));
```

Starting at the 100th item in the Firebase and ending at 200?  I know I can use a skip filter  but that still seems to load the first 100 items, correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are on the right track. You attach the [startAt](https://www.firebase.com/docs/javascript/firebase/startat.html)().[limit](https://www.firebase.com/docs/javascript/firebase/limit.html)() code to the Firebase ref and then pass that into $firebase as you have above.

However, the [startAt](https://www.firebase.com/docs/javascript/firebase/startat.html) method does not take a numeric offset, but instead a priority and optionally a record id (key).

So where you have put startAt(100), attempting to start after record 100, you would instead need to use the record ID, or prioritize the records in groups of 100.

For background, [here's a simple paginator](http://jsfiddle.net/katowulf/yumaB/) you can check out and steal ideas from. The heart of the example is in nextPage, where it calls startAt using the previous record id like so:

```
var lastKey = null; // page 0
this.ref.startAt(null, lastKey)
   .limit(this.limit + (lastKey? 1 : 0))
   .once('value', /* callback to process data goes here */));
```

**UPDATE**

Another useful note here is that the records returned by angularFire contain their unique id as `$id`, which can be useful for determining the id of the last iterated item.